# How to connect to Cloud SQL (2nd Generation) via MySQL Proxy Docker Container over TCP

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Running on Mac OS X, I have been trying to connect to a Cloud SQL instance via the proxy using [these directions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-docker). Once you have installed the MySQL client, gce-proxy container, and have created a service account in Google Cloud Platform, you get down to running these two commands specified in the documentation:

```
docker run -d -v /cloudsql:/cloudsql \
  -v [LOCAL_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH]:[LOCAL_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH] \
  b.gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy /cloud_sql_proxy \
  -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306 -credential_file=[CLOUD_KEY_FILE_PATH]

mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -p
```

First, I don't understand how this should ever work, since the container is not exposing a port. So unsurprisingly, when I attempted to connect I get the following error from the MySQL client:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

But if I do expose the port by adding `-p 3306:3306` to the `docker run` command, I still can't connect. Instead I get the following error from MySQL client:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

I have successfully connected to the proxy running `cloud_sql_proxy` on my docker host machine by following [that documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy), so I am confident my credential file and my mysql client is configured correctly. The logs of the container do not state that any connection was attempted. I have no problem connecting to a normal mysql container via docker. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried @Vadim's suggestion, which is basically this:

```
docker run -d -v /cloudsql:/cloudsql \
  -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 \ 
  -v [LOCAL_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH]:[LOCAL_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH] \
  b.gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy /cloud_sql_proxy \
  -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306 -credential_file=[CLOUD_KEY_FILE_PATH]
```

I was still unable to get a connection, as I still got this error:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

However, the logs of the docker container showed a connection, like so:

```
2016/10/16 07:52:32 New connection for "[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]"
2016/10/16 07:52:32 couldn't connect to "[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]": Post https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/[PROJECT_NAME]/instances/[CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_NAME]/createEphemeral?alt=json: oauth2: cannot fetch token: Post https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token: x509: failed to load system roots and no roots provided
```

So now it appeared that it was getting the traffic, but it not find the certificates for the SSL container. I had used [OpenSSL's `cert.pem` export of my certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28274272/735679) and mounted it to the same location in the docker container. It makes sense that an arbitrary mapping of `[LOCAL_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH]:[LOCAL_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH]` wasn't helping the proxy figure out where the certificates were. So I used a clue from [this Kubernetes setup guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/container-engine-samples/blob/master/cloudsql/cloudsql_deployment.yaml#L50) and change the mounted volume to `-v [LOCAL_CERTIFICATE_FILE_PATH]:/etc/ssl/certs`. Mercifully, that worked.

**TL;DR** - Here is the final syntax for getting the Docker Container to run over TCP:

```
docker run -d \
    -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 \
    -v [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY_DIRECTORY]:[SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY_DIRECTORY] \
    -v [LOCAL_CERTIFICATE_DIRECTORY]:/etc/ssl/certs \
    b.gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy /cloud_sql_proxy \
    -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306 \
    -credential_file=[SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY_JSON_FILE]
```

Comment: To clarify, the certs file is for root CA certs. You don't need to provide the Cloud SQL certs to the proxy.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure out how to use cloudsql-proxy on my local docker environment by using docker-compose. You will need to pull down your Cloud SQL instance credentials and have them ready. I keep them them in my project root as `credentials.json` and add it to my `.gitignore` in the project.

The key part I found was using `=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432` after the GCP instance ID so that the port can be forwarded. Then, in your application, use `cloudsql-proxy` instead of `localhost` as the hostname. Make sure the rest of your db creds are valid in your application secrets so that it can connect through local proxy being supplied by the cloudsql-proxy container.

Note: Keep in mind I'm writing a tomcat java application and my `docker-compose.yml` reflects that.

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
    version: '3'
    services:
      cloudsql-proxy:
          container_name: cloudsql-proxy
          image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
          command: /cloud_sql_proxy --dir=/cloudsql -instances=<YOUR INSTANCE ID HERE>=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432 -credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json
          ports:
            - 5432:5432
          volumes:
            - ./credentials.json:/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json
          restart: always
    
      tomcatapp-api:
        container_name: tomcatapp-api
        build: .
        volumes:
          - ./build/libs:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps
        ports:
          - 8080:8080
          - 8000:8000
        env_file:
          - ./secrets.env
        restart: always
```

Answer (score 1):

It does look like there are some omissions in the documentation.

1) As you point out, you need to expose the port from the container. You'll want to make sure you only expose it to the local machine by specifying `-p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306`.

2) Then when running the container, you'll want to expose the port outside the container by specifying `-instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306`