# brew install fails: curl(77) error setting certificate verify

Tags: macos, curl, homebrew, libcurl

ok, so im running an old Mac 10.6.8 with homebrew. brew doctor reports no errors and i have tried brew prune update etc. Everytime i try to install a package, i get this error:

```
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
```

ive tried everything, openssl is installed, but the folder mentioned

```
/usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
```

as well as

```
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

is not there. can anyone save me?

Full Sample:

```
jonathan-fullers-iMac% brew install git 
Updating Homebrew...
==> Installing dependencies for git: xz
==> Installing git dependency: xz
==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/lzmautils/xz-5.2.3.tar

curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading https://tukaani.org/xz/xz-5.2.3.tar.gz

curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
Error: Failed to download resource "xz"
Download failed: https://tukaani.org/xz/xz-5.2.3.tar.gz
```

brew doctor reports:

```
jonathan-fullers-iMac% brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: You are using macOS 10.6.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You may encounter build failures or other breakages.
Please create pull-requests instead of filing issues.
```

**Edit**

Found a stray .curlrc file, removed it, now error changed to:

```
jonathan-fullers-iMac% curl https://github.com
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
```

But the PEM file is there...:

```
jonathan-fullers-iMac% pwd && echo "\r\n" && ls
/usr/local/etc/openssl
cert.pem    certs       misc        openssl.cnf private
```

Here is my Path, just in case:

```
jonathan-fullers-iMac% echo $PATH
/Users/werlious/.bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/X11/bin
```

**Another Edit**
I tried reinstalling openssl, install gave me no errors but uninstall gave me:

```
jonathan-fullers-iMac% brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies openssl && brew install openssl
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2l... (1,701 files, 12.7MB)
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl
  Reason: image not found
Updating Homebrew...
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl
  Reason: image not found
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl
  Reason: image not found
```

**Yet Another Update** 
So after reinstallingopenssl, i now have this:

```
jonathan-fullers-iMac% brew install python
Updating Homebrew...
==> Installing dependencies for python: readline, sqlite, gdbm
==> Installing python dependency: readline
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-7.0.tar.gz
  curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
   CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
   CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
Trying a mirror... 
==> Downloading https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/readline/readline-7.0.tar.gz
==> Downloading from http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/gnu/ftp/gnu/readline/readline-7.
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-7.0-patches/readline70

curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
  CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/readline/readline-7.0-patches/readline
==> Downloading from http://mirror.easthsia.com/gnu/readline/readline-7.0-patche
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-7.0-patches/readline70

curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
  CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
Trying a mirror... 
==> Downloading https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/readline/readline-7.0-patches/readline
==> Downloading from http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/gnu/ftp/gnu/readline/readline-7.
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-7.0-patches/readline70

curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
  CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading https://ftpmirror.gnu.org/readline/readline-7.0-patches/readline
==> Downloading from http://mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net/gnu/readline/readlin
 ######################################################################## 100.0%
 ==> Patching
==> Applying readline70-001
patching file history.c
patching file patchlevel  
==> Applying readline70-002
patching file history.c
patching file patchlevel
==> Applying readline70-003
patching file input.c
patching file patchlevel
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.3_1
==> make install
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides the BSD libedit library, which shadows libreadline.
In order to prevent conflicts when programs look for libreadline we are
defaulting this GNU Readline installation to keg-only..
For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
   LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib
   CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include

==> Summary
/usr/local/Cellar/readline/7.0.3_1: 46 files, 1.5MB, built in 3 minutes 6 seconds
==> Installing python dependency: sqlite
==> Downloading https://sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-autoconf-3200000.tar.gz

curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
  CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
Error: Failed to download resource "sqlite"
Download failed: https://sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-autoconf-3200000.tar.gz
```

Im so lost. i have no idea what is goin on from this point

Comment: If anyone with the same problem needs a half baked solution you can download the packages .tar.xz and place it into ~/Library/caches/Homebrew

Comment: Homebrew doesn’t support macOS 10.6. Consider using [Tigerbrew](https://github.com/mistydemeo/tigerbrew) instead.

Answer (score 28):

This error message indicates that curl is not able to establish a secure connection using openssl
you can:

first

```
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

then reinstall openssl and curl

```
HOMEBREW_CURLRC=1 brew reinstall openssl curl
```

last

```
sed -i '/^insecure$/d' ~/.curlrc
git config --global http.sslVerify true
```

Comment: This worked for me. I did not need to change to git config though, just the curl config file was enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24694579/7909920)

Goto the keychain access, and export all the system root certificates into the /usr/local/etc/openssl directory

Answer (score 2):

Stone Info Labs's solution worked well—

Want to add clarity—

There will/should be a cert.pem file already in /usr/local/etc/openssl 
It may be a blank one. 
When you export the system root certificate from Keychain, 
Certificates.pem will need to be renamed to cert.pem 
Otherwise you can copy and paste the raw certificate code into that file.

You'll be brewin' in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting mad about this issue. My fix was as follows:

```
brew install openssl@3
mkdir -p  /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/
ln -s /usr/local/etc/openssl@3/cert.pem /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs/cert.pem 
rbenv install 3.1.2
# success
```

See here [Rbenv install 3.1.2 fails on Mac 12.6 (21G115) #2061
@ rbenv/ruby-build](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/2061)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying `brew tap aws/tap` and got the same error `error setting certificate verify locations:  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem CApath: none`

I tried `git config --global http.sslverify false` and still no fix, I then ran `git config --list` and found there were two configs in the config list for some weird reason -
`http.sslverify=false`
and
`http.sslverify=true`
I removed the second one and it worked.
Hope this helps someone, good luck.