# TypeError: SSLContext.wrap_socket() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sock'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, ssl

the code is:

```
import ssl 
import socket 
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
ssl_sock = ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket(sock)
```

the error is:
TypeError: SSLContext.wrap_socket() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sock'

I don't understand why I get the error and how should I solve it since i provided the argument mentioned above.

Comment: I think you are missing a lot of stuff. Example: [What's the function of \`context.load\_verify\_locations("/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt")\` in python ssl coding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63786335)

Comment: thank you, i thought it's the same as ssl.wrap_socket(sock) which i tried before, however i got an error that it's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

`wrap_socket` is a method which need to be called on the context **object**, i.e.

```
ssl_sock = ssl.SSLContext().wrap_socket(sock)
```

not

```
ssl_sock = ssl.SSLContext.wrap_socket(sock)
```